# Mapping Rows of Two Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I'm working with two DataFrames,

**df1**

```
altitude
132 16.324794
133 16.027025
134 15.738367
135 15.462613
136 15.195307
137 14.934009
138 14.682448
139 14.440509
140 14.207593
141 14.070644
```

**df2**

```
altitude    density east_wind   north_wind
0   5   0.020567    39.714397   6.795392
1   7   0.016871    41.171996   6.852655
2   9   0.013839    42.629594   6.909918
3   11  0.011351    44.087193   6.967182
4   13  0.009311    45.544791   7.024445
5   15  0.007638    47.003028   7.079618
6   17  0.006263    48.303168   7.340789
7   19  0.005129    48.942837   8.478684
8   21  0.004201    49.588021   9.587021
9   23  0.003433    50.797853   11.256209
```

I'd like to map the `altitude` in df1 to the closest  `altitude` in df2 and eventually merging the `density` `east_wind` and `north_wind` values of that row to a new Dataframe.

**Expected Result**

```
altitude    density east_wind   north_wind
132 16.324794   0.006263   48.303168   7.340789
136 15.195307   0.007638   47.003028   7.079618
137 14.934009   0.007638   47.003028   7.079618
```

Please Advise

Comment: How 132 (value of altitude in df1) became closest to 17 (value of altitude in df2) as per your expected output?

Comment: `132` is the index value, `16.324794` is the `altitude` and it is mapped to `17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the closest `df2.altitude` index using [**`idxmin`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```py
df1['df2_idx'] = df1.altitude.apply(lambda x: df2.altitude.sub(x).abs().idxmin())

#      altitude   df2_idx
# 132  16.324794  6
# 133  16.027025  6
# 134  15.738367  5
# 135  15.462613  5
# 136  15.195307  5
# 137  14.934009  5
# 138  14.682448  5
# 139  14.440509  5
# 140  14.207593  5
# 141  14.070644  5
```

And then [**`merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `df1.df2_idx` and `df2.index`:

```py
df1.merge(df2.drop('altitude', axis=1), left_on='df2_idx', right_index=True).drop('df2_idx', axis=1)

#      altitude   density   east_wind  north_wind
# 132  16.324794  0.006263  48.303168  7.340789
# 133  16.027025  0.006263  48.303168  7.340789
# 134  15.738367  0.007638  47.003028  7.079618
# 135  15.462613  0.007638  47.003028  7.079618
# 136  15.195307  0.007638  47.003028  7.079618
# 137  14.934009  0.007638  47.003028  7.079618
# 138  14.682448  0.007638  47.003028  7.079618
# 139  14.440509  0.007638  47.003028  7.079618
# 140  14.207593  0.007638  47.003028  7.079618
# 141  14.070644  0.007638  47.003028  7.079618
```

Comment: Just the answer I had in mind! Please tweak the second part of your answer there seem to be an extra set of parentheses

Comment: Sure, the outer parentheses were only there to allow line wrapping. I went ahead and removed them.